# Regular expression keyword filtering

Tags: javascript, regex, keyword-search

I'm trying to build a search using regular expression which uses specific terms to split and and filter the search query. For example, if I have a query like:
`artist rolling stones track stupid girl track paint it black`, it will pull out albums which are by Rolling Stones and has the tracks stupid girl and paint it black on. Ideally (after a bit of processing) I'd send the data up to the server like this: `{ artists : ['rolling stone'], tracks : ['stupid girl', 'paint it black'] }`.

I have a basic regex which matches the keyword (artist/track) and the first word after the keyword (rolling/stupid/paint), however if I make it match the spaces and the words after, it just matches the whole string.

This is the regex I currently have: `(artist|track)\s([\w]+)`. I'm guessing I need to use stop words or something to create a boundary between phrases, but I'm not super experienced with building regex. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post your input and output clearly?

Comment: Input: `artist rolling stones track stupid girl track paint it black`. I want the regex to find the phrases: "artist rolling stone", "track stupid girl", "track paint it black".

Comment: There can be an unlimited number of `artist artist name` and `track track name` phrases in the query string. There may also be no tracks or and just an artist or maybe even the other way around. Does this sufficiently clarify for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(artist|track).*?(?=artist|track|$)
```

try this code

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$string =~ s{artist\s*((?:(?!track|$).)+)track\s*((?:(?!track|$).)+)(?:track((?:(?!track|$).)+))?}{artists : ['$1'], tracks : ['$2','$3']}ig;
```

Try this code.
use this regex

```
artist\s*((?:(?!track|$).)+)track\s*((?:(?!track|$).)+)(?:track((?:(?!track|$).)+))?
```

replace:

```
artists : ['$1'], tracks : ['$2','$3']
```

Comment: Okay, so that works in the very specific case that I have one artist and two tracks. What about if I have a varying number of tracks/artists?

Comment: (artist|track).*?(?=artist|track|$) try this